# Add a class if url is equal to href of a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a jQuery script in WordPress, that will add the "active" class to the element of my sidebar that has the same URL as the matching link in the navbar.

```js
(function ($) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    $('.navbar-nav li').each(function ($) {
        if ($('.navbar-nav li a').attr('href') == url) {
            $('.navbar-nav li').addClass('active');
        }
    });
    console.log(url);
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.active {
background-color: black;}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-white"> 
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item menu_accueil only-mobile">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo get_site_url() ?>/">
                Accueil
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item menu_marque">
          <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo get_site_url() ?>/la-marque-honey">
            La marque 
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item menu_formule">
          <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo get_site_url().'/la-formule-honey' ?>">
            La formule 
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item menu_bebe">
          <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo get_site_url() ?>/conseil">
            Le monde de bébé
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </nav>
```

It shows an error ( $ is not a function ), while there's another piece of code on the website that works well with the same selectors.

What's the issue here ?
Thanks

Comment: Did you put this script before the jQuery include?

Comment: I didn't setup the website, but yeah, we use grunt to concatenate all the files, and some other JS files on the website work well, so jQuery is already loaded when the script runs

Comment: if you have included jquery and still getting same error then just `console` the `$` in your function and check if its the correct jquery function.

Comment: I just did a  console.log($)  and it says " undefined "

Comment: Then jquery library is not included in your page. Make sure to include it first.

Comment: The arguments to jquery `each` are the index and element being iterated over. If you're not using them you can remove the `$` from the argument to the inner function; you're shadowing the outer one so you can't use jquery in your inner function.

Comment: Well first issue is you have the code running before jQuery if it is included on the page. Second is the code is wrong. You are reading the same link on every iteration of the loop.

Comment: have you tried echo'ing the url value after initializing it, to compare it with the value of the href? Mainly, to check for relative vs full paths.

Comment: I moved my piece of code to another piece of code that is working well, and it works. Also I moved the console.log(url) to before the if, and it properly displays, so it's probably my if that is causing the statement, or am I mistaking ?

Comment: @MaelLandrin isn't it just easier to use the `:active` pseudo selector in css? Do you really need javascript and jQuery for this? Why isn't plain CSS not enough?

Comment: I completely agree with @nvioli .  The `$` passed into the each is going to make the $ not jQuery in the each logic.

Comment: Also keep in mind that once you get your jQuery issue worked out, you could also potentially reduce your logic to `$('.navbar-nav li').has('a[href="'+ url +'"]').addClass('active');`

Answer (score 2):

> It shows an error ( $ is not a function )

This error was because you were redefining `$` inside the each as the element being iterated:

```
 $('.navbar-nav li').each(function ($) {
 // Dont do this -------------------^
```

There were a few things wrong with your code, but in general what you were doing was using selectors within the whole page instead of selectors with the current element being enumerated using `each`

```js
$(function() {

  var url = window.location.href;
  $('.navbar-nav li').each(function() {
    if ($('a',this).attr('href') == url) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
  console.log(url);


});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<nav class="navbar fixed-top ">
  <div class="" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item menu_accueil only-mobile">
        <a class="nav-link" href="xxx">
                Accueil
            </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item menu_marque">
        <a class="nav-link" href="xxx">
            La marque 
          </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item menu_formule">
        <a class="nav-link" href="https://stacksnippets.net/js">
            La formule 
          </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item menu_bebe">
        <a class="nav-link" href="xxx">
            Le monde de bébé
          </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Tried it, and there's no error, but it doesn't do anything to the classes unfortunately

Comment: @MaelLandrin well as I demonstrated here with one href which exactly matches the url it works. Have you tried `console.log` exactly your href and url? They will need to match exactly

Comment: Riiight apparently when I console this : var anchor = $('.navbar-nav li').children('a').attr('href');
    console.log(window.location.href);
    console.log(anchor); I see that the first console.log shows http://localhost/mywebsite/la-marque-honey, and the 2nd shows http://localhost/mywebsite which is weird because in the inspector, the href is the full url

Comment: Okay I see it now, I'm stupid and i forgot to add it in the code, but the first <li> is not "la-marque-honey" but actually the logo. So there was a difference of one index in the each()

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your jquery script is loaded before your function is called. Just make sure the jquery script tag is before the script tag containing your code.

Aside from your initial error - what you have here will add `.active` to every `li` that's a child of `.navbar-nav`.

```
$('.navbar-nav li').each(function ($) {//So is $ in the function parenthisis
    if ($('.navbar-nav li a').attr('href') == url) {
        $('.navbar-nav li').addClass('active');//this is wrong
    }
});
```

You should make use of the `this` keyword. Something like

```
$('.navbar-nav li').each(function () {
    let anchor = $(this).children('a');
    if ($(anchor).attr('href') == url) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: @epascarello I'm under the impression he doesn't want to add to every anchor on the page

Comment: I'm not getting any error now, but it just doesn't do anything, and yes @SeanT is right I only want one item to be active.

Comment: You need to just swap out the code I posted of yours with mine, make sure it's still in the parent function `(function ($) {});` @MaelLandrin

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    $('.navbar-nav li').each(function ($) {
        if ($('.navbar-nav li a').attr('href') == url) {
            $('.navbar-nav li').addClass('active');
        }
    });
    console.log(url);
});
```

Comment: Also include jQuery before you load your script.
So:
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="my-script.js"></script>